# Problem installing Cairo library using VCPKG

Tags: c++, cmake, cairo, vcpkg

I am a newbie programming student and have stumbled with this issue for quite a long time.
I am trying to install the Io2D library as instrcuted in this link:https://github.com/cpp-io2d/P0267_RefImpl/blob/master/BUILDING.md

However, every time I try to install Cairo I get this error:

```
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_required_process.cmake:96 (message):
    Command failed: "C:/Program Files/src/vcpkg/downloads/tools/msys2/7e05e7aa09f1709f/usr/bin/bash.exe" --noprofile --norc --debug -c "V=1 CPP='compile cl.exe -E' CC='compile cl.exe' CC_FOR_BUILD='compile cl.exe' CXX='compile cl.exe' RC='windres-rc rc.exe' WINDRES='windres-rc rc.exe' AR='ar-lib lib.exe' LD='link.exe -verbose' RANLIB=':' STRIP=':' NM='dumpbin.exe -symbols -headers' DLLTOOL='link.exe -verbose -dll' CCAS=':' AS=':' ./../src/1.17-e2a53830aa.clean/configure --build=i686-pc-mingw32 \"--enable-extra-encodings\" \"--without-libiconv-prefix\" \"--without-libintl-prefix\" \"--enable-relocatable\" \"ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_STRIP=:\" \"gl_cv_double_slash_root=yes\" \"ac_cv_func_memmove=yes\" \"--disable-silent-rules\" \"--verbose\" \"--enable-shared\" \"--disable-static\" \"--prefix=/C/Program Files/src/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/debug\" \"--bindir=\\${prefix}/../tools/libiconv/debug/bin\" \"--sbindir=\\${prefix}/../tools/libiconv/debug/sbin\" \"--libdir=\\${prefix}/lib\" \"--includedir=\\${prefix}/../include\" \"--datarootdir=\\${prefix}/share/libiconv\""
    Working Directory: C:/Program Files/src/vcpkg/buildtrees/libiconv/x86-windows-dbg
    Error code: This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher
    See logs for more information:

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  scripts/cmake/vcpkg_configure_make.cmake:707 (vcpkg_execute_required_process)
  ports/libiconv/portfile.cmake:29 (vcpkg_configure_make)
  scripts/ports.cmake:146 (include)


error: building libiconv:x86-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED
Please ensure you're using the latest port files with `git pull` and `vcpkg update`.
Then check for known issues at:
    https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+in%3Atitle+libiconv
You can submit a new issue at:
    https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/new?template=report-package-build-failure.md&title=[libiconv]+Build+error
Include '[libiconv] Build error' in your bug report title, the following version information in your bug description, and attach any relevant failure logs from above.
    vcpkg-tool version: 2022-06-17-9268e366206712e38102b28dbd1617697a99ff2e
    vcpkg-scripts version: 98f8d00e8 2022-07-08 (3 days ago)

You can also use the prefilled template from C:\Program Files\src\vcpkg\installed\vcpkg\issue_body.md.
```

Comment: `CC='compile cl.exe'` this looks wrong

Answer (score 0):

Vcpkg doesn't ship with any of the niche stuff required for building some of these libraries. Cairo seems to require Bison and it makes use of anototations import that are only supported from Python version 3.7+.

So first install Bison, then make sure you have a minimum version of python 3.7 and cairo installation should work fine (in theory). I had to do this on ubuntu 18.04.